# jQuery DataTable: inserting export buttons in server-side datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have created a dataTable that gets data from my database. I successfully did it and wanted to add export buttons in my dataTable. When I try to copy the code from the example [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html), no data is showing up in the datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shms_grid').DataTable( {
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
       "serverSide": true,
       "processing": true,
       "ajax":{
         url :"shms_data.php",
         type: "post",
         error: function(){
           $(".shms_grid_error").html("");
           $("#shms_grid").append('<tbody class="shms_grid_error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
           $("#shms_grid_processing").css("display","none");
         }
       },
       buttons: [
          'copyHtml5',
          'excelHtml5',
          'csvHtml5',
          'pdfHtml5'
      ]
     });
  });
```

I then tried the code below and it shows the entries in the datatable but the buttons are nowhere to be found. What is the proper way of creating these export buttons? I've also already called all the required scripts in my html file. Thanks for any help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shms_grid').DataTable( {
      //dom: 'Bfrtip',
       "serverSide": true,
       "processing": true,
       "ajax":{
         url :"shms_data.php",
         type: "post",
         error: function(){
           $(".shms_grid_error").html("");
           $("#shms_grid").append('<tbody class="shms_grid_error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
           $("#shms_grid_processing").css("display","none");
         }
       }
     });
  });

  $(window).load(function(){
    console.log("load");
    $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
          'copyHtml5',
          'excelHtml5',
          'csvHtml5',
          'pdfHtml5'
      ]
    });
 });
```